# Hibernate - some records are missing while fetching the table using Where IN clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

Am trying to fetch the table by passing list of ids. But some of the records are missing after the select statement.

Please find my code below.

```
System.out.println("UserID List Size:::"+userId_list.size());
String userHQL = "from User where id in (:userId_list )";
Query userQuery = session.createQuery(userHQL);
userQuery.setParameterList("userId_list", userId_list);
List<User> user_list=userQuery.list();
for(User user:user_list)
  {
    System.out.println(user.getId());
  }
```

Am getting `userId_list` from another table and `userId_list.size()`  is 70. But after the select statement am getting only 51 instead of 70 records.

Some of the records are missing during the fetching process.

Comment: remove the parenthesis you don't think they make sense in your case

Comment: maybe in your User class you have implmented equals method?